# connecting OPEN API from a neutral server

Tags: bloomberg

I want to run my application (based on OPEN API) on a server on which Bloomberg Terminal is not installed. But I have to pass by a Bloomberg server.

Look at "Figure 7-2: Server API: Server Mode: Authorization by IP Address" on page 80 of "blpapi-developers-guide.pdf".

Please let know how this can be done.

Or how setup EMRS in order to allow an application to be given entitlements and services to consume?

Thank you.

Comment: please provide a link to the stated pdf file.

Comment: http://www.openbloomberg.com/files/2012/03/blpapi-developers-guide.pdf

Answer (score 3):

**IMPORTANT:** This method is not compatible with Bloomberg licence agreement. Use it only for debug purposes.

Download PasPort application from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pjs-passport/) and install it. PassPort is a simple port forwarding utility. The program runs as an NT Service. It is easily manageable with a simple Windows GUI.

For example your computer with Bloomberg terminal has ip 192.168.8.40, then you need to setup PassPort application as following:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Don't forget to add a rule to the firewall in Windows:

[image]

[image]

Now you can access terminal from any computer on the local network. Furthermore, you can setup access to terminal behind a firewall.

For example you can run on computer with ip 192.168.8.41 the such command:

```
java -jar SimpleFieldInfoExample-3.6.1-0.jar -ip 192.168.8.40 -p 8194
```

And it is working now!

Of course you also need to run bbcomm.exe on Bloomberg terminal using Start menu:

[image]

[image]

It is possible to activate bbcomm without any window using command:

```
java -jar SimpleFieldInfoExample-3.6.1-0.jar -ip localhost -p 8194
```

Or you can launch the "Bloomberg API DEMO" application.

Answer (score 2):

There is a simpler way to pass a port:

```
netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenport=8194 listenaddress=192.168.0.101 connectport=8194 connectaddress=localhost
```